# How to create const objects from non-const objects

Tags: c++

I am not sure how to exactly express my thoughts and hence my googling is failing but is there a way to create const objects from non-const objects?

For instance, my graph class is as follows:

```
class graph 
{
    public: 
        graph( int n )
        {
                adj_list.resize( n );
                adj_mat_wgt.resize( n, std::vector<double>( n ,100.0 ) ); 
                _n = n;
        };

        ~graph() {}; 

        void add_arc( int u, int v, double wit ); 

        std::vector<int> get_shortest_path( int source, int sink );
        void             set_const_gs_weights();

    private: 
        std::vector<std::vector<int>>          adj_list;
        std::vector<std::vector<double>>       adj_mat_wgt;
        int                                    _n;
};
}
```

I want to create another private variable and use `set_const_gs_weights` to create a copy  of `adj_mat_wgt` but has some constness such that it can never be changed. The reason for this is that I will be modifying `adj_mat_wgt` though some functions and I need to go back to the original `adj_mat_wgt` by taking a non-const copy of the const object that I would like to create.

I understand that I can always just create another non-const variable like `adj_mat_wgt_cpy` and store a copy of `adj_mat_wgt` in it and never touch it except for using it to create another fresh copy for `adj_mat_wgt` after my changes. But is there a way to make `adj_mat_wgt_cpy` const? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can always use a `const` pointer.

Comment: Your lats paragraph sounds like you know the solution: add a member variable and declare the variable `const`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think you can do this as a member variable. Member variables have to be initialized when the constructor runs, which means that if you don't set a `const` member variable by then, you won't have an opportunity to change your mind later by calling `set_const_gs_weights`. Perhaps you could have a flag that you check in `set_const_gs_weights` and if it's flagged the function is a no-op.

Comment: A one-time lazily settable object? I can't think of any tool for that. Maybe `std::optional<const T>`?

Comment: But what is your real problem here? Are you afraid that you will modify the copy accidentally? Or that others might do so? Or what?

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks! That is exactly what I am looking for. No changes can be made to it after it is set.

Comment: @TonyK just want to know if there is a way. I mean it is a personal project and I am sure I can ensure not to touch it but if there is a way to make it just one time settable object.

Comment: Unrelated: [The Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) suggests you remove or explicitly `default` the destructor

Comment: Usually this kind of question suggests a design problem.  _Sometimes_ it's appropriate to declare a member variable as `mutable` IF it's purely for some kind of non-stateful purpose that doesn't affect the object's constness.  A mutex is a good example of this, or some kind of lazy-built cache.  More often than not, you're stuck in some kind of thought process that's causing you to attempt a weird design.

Comment: Does `std::optional<const T>` actually even work? When I try to do something like it it tells me that `operator=` is deleted on it.